# Matlab code formatting similar to AStyle?

Tags: matlab, ide, coding-style, code-formatting

Is there any tool similar to AStyle to format matlab code in m-files?

Comment: I know it is an old question, but if you are interested, see my answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23960822/how-can-i-reformat-codes-in-matlab-editor/37362250#37362250

Answer (score 6):

In recent versions of MATLAB, you can use the "Smart Indent" tool programmatically using the [MATLAB Editor API](http://blogs.mathworks.com/desktop/2011/05/09/r2011a-matlab-editor-api/).

As an example, say you want to fix indentation of all M-files contained in a specific directory:

```
%# gel list of m-files in a directory
BASE_DIR = 'c:\path\to\folder';
files = dir( fullfile(BASE_DIR,'*.m') );
files = {files.name};

for i=1:numel(files)
    %# open file in editor, apply smart indentation, save and close
    doc = matlab.desktop.editor.openDocument( fullfile(BASE_DIR,files{i}) );
    doc.smartIndentContents;
    doc.save;
    doc.close;
end
```

Comment: thanks for the smart snippet. I'd like to format whitespace also

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you can select text in Matlab's editor and press `Ctrl+I` to auto-indent it. (Also , use `Ctrl+A` to select all the text.)

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/19056-m-file-code-formatting-tool