# matlab code formatter

Tags: matlab

Are there any existing free matlab formatters? I know that matlab auto indents code, but I have a mess of code that I've been typing up in a text doc and for some reason my code always become messy even while using matlab.

I can find plenty of C, php, etc formatters out there, why are there none for matlab?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861006/matlab-code-formatting-similar-to-astyle

Comment: I know it is an old one, but if you are interested, please see my answer regarding MBeautifier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23960822/how-can-i-reformat-codes-in-matlab-editor/37362250#37362250

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to smart indent the current file, you can do <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +
 <kbd>a</kbd> (to select all) then <kbd>ctrl</kbd> +
 <kbd>i</kbd> (to smart indent the selection).